# DualBoot with two disks on BIOS level

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have two disks. W10 is installed on one disk. I want to install Ubuntu on the other disk. I hate fiddling around with MBR and fixing Grub when anything goes wrong. Therefore, I thought it would be a good idea to install Ubuntu on the other disk. And do the boot decision on bios-level. Is this possible and maybe even preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible, and a very good idea, because if anything goes very wrong, you can reinstall it easily. The fact that each OS has its own HDD is good, too, since it gives you more control over each of them.